# unix minishell char into **char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

so basically what I want to do:

If i write

> Hello I am here

`char command[20]` should be '**Hello**'(that part works) and `char *parameters` should have pointers which point at '**Hello**' '**I**' '**am**' '**here**' '**NULL**'.

For the '**Hello**' part i just used `char *com` which is already a Pointer. But i don't really know how to get the rest right.

Basically: `execvp` wants an `char` with the command and an array of pointers which point at the command and all the parameters (i hope that part is right).

I don't know how to fill `*parameters`.

I fear the answer is really obvious :(

Thanks in advance

```
void read_command(char *com, char **par) 
{

 string Eingabe = " ";

 fprintf(stdout, "$ ");

 getline (cin, Eingabe);

 strcpy(com, Eingabe.substr(0, Eingabe.find(" ")).c_str());
 *par = com;    

 Eingabe.erase(0, Eingabe.find(" ")+1); 

  do
 {
 par++;

 strcpy( ???, Eingabe.substr(0, Eingabe.find(" ")).c_str());
 Eingabe.erase(0, Eingabe.find(" ")+1);



 }while();

return; 
}




int main()
{
 int childPid;
 int status;
 char command[20];
 char *parameters[60];

while(1) 
{

    read_command(command, parameters);

    if((childPid = fork()) == -1)
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "can't fork\n");
     exit(1);
    }else if(childPid == 0)
    {
     execvp(command, parameters);
     exit(0);
    }else
    {
    waitpid(childPid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Your do-while in read_command is missing its "while" expression.

2) You're mixing C++ and C-style string manipulation in a way that doesn't seem intuitive to me. I'd strongly recommend picking one style and sticking to it.

3) The operation of splitting a string up the way you want is referred to as "tokenizing" - try searching with that term. Interesting C functions might include strtok and/or strcspn. In C++, the Boost Tokenizer might help you out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer. I will check for solutions on tokenizing, but thats not really the issue in this case. My problem is not the seperation of the String, its how do i put them into char *parameters[60].
F.e. if i have  an char, wich contains 'here' in the function read_command, how do i get this char into char *parameters[], so that parameters[1][0] would be 'h' and [1][1] would be 'e' and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic zero-copy C-style implementation might look like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    char command[20];
    char *parameters[60];
    int i, childPid, status;

    while(1) {
        memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));
        memset(parameters, 0, sizeof(parameters));

        i = 0;

        gets(command);

        parameters[i] = strtok(command, " ");
        i++;
        while(parameters[i] = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
            //turn the space before us into a null terminator
            *(parameters[i] - 1) = '\0';
            i++;
        }

        if(childPid = fork()) { //assume success, we're the parent
            waitpid(childPid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        }
        else { //we're the child
            execvp(command, parameters);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You're using strtok to step through your command string, saving the location of each parameter as you go. *And* you're modifying the command string in-place to replace a ' ' delimiter with a null terminator, chopping up the input string as you go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the program is working fine after i added "#include <stdlib.h>"
Your way of handling the incoming command and parameters looks a lot easier than the way i was doing it, so thank you for that.
But I dont really want to have the program in main() only, I have to add some more functionalitys and it could get a bit messy then. 

So i'm still looking for a solution where its seperated.